# when insert Large number of data Python's elasticsearch bulk API trigger OOM

Tags: python, elasticsearch

when i use above code to insert data to elasticsearch,　trigger OOM

```
import time
import sys
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch.helpers import bulk

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

def set_mapping(es, index_name = "content_engine", doc_type_name = "en"):
    my_mapping = {
        "en": {
            "properties": {
                "a": {
                    "type": "string"
                 },
                 "b": {
                    "type": "string"
                 }
            }
        }
    }
    create_index = es.indices.create(index = index_name,body = my_mapping)
    mapping_index = es.indices.put_mapping(index = index_name, doc_type = doc_type_name, body = my_mapping)
    if create_index["acknowledged"] != True or mapping_index["acknowledged"] != True:
        print "Index creation failed..."

def set_data(es, input_file, index_name = "content_engine", doc_type_name="en"):
    i = 0
    count = 0
    ACTIONS = []
    for line in open(input_file):
        fields = line.replace("\r\n", "").replace("\n", "").split("----")
        if len(fields) == 2:
            a, b = fields
        else:
            continue
        action = {
            "_index": index_name,
            "_type": doc_type_name,
            "_source": {
                  "a": a,
                  "b": b, 
            }
        }
        i += 1
        ACTIONS.append(action)
        if (i == 500000):
            success, _ = bulk(es, ACTIONS, index = index_name, raise_on_error = True)
            count += success
            i = 0
            ACTIONS = []

    success, _ = bulk(es, ACTIONS, index = index_name, raise_on_error=True)
    count += success
    print("insert %s lines" % count)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    es = Elasticsearch(hosts=["127.0.0.1:9200"], timeout=5000)
    set_mapping(es)
    set_data(es,sys.argv[1])
```

my machine's memory is 24G,data's size is 5G, when insert 1600w lines,The memory began soaring，finally trigger OOM, where trigger Memory leak。

Comment: What was the error you received

Comment: Python process received killed。it's  killed by kernel。

Comment: have you tried reducing the action count? it's much higher than the default chunking factor anyway. Make it 50k and see what happens.

Comment: OOM are usually the result of too much data being sent, you need to lower the amount of data you send until it gets through... Trial and error...

Comment: @pvg yeah, i already tried reduing the action count, but it still oom.

Comment: @Val ok, i'll try split the big file.

Comment: try https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler

Comment: @firebroo. Did you solved this problem?. I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: how much is assigned to the heap out of that ?